# I can't understand recursive or iterative dynamic loops in Python

Tags: arrays, list, loops, recursion, nested-loops

I have tried to tell you guys about how to dynamic loop yesterday, and you answered either with recursion or iter, but I honestly don't yet understand the picture. So I am going to be more specific today.

Say, The user has been asked for the number of fields, and he chooses 3.

So, there will be a loop, for an array, or a dictionary with keys, say `var`, filling them with 3 entries.

What I want is to make nested loops such that in pseudo code, it acts like

```
for i in var[0]:
   for j in var[1]:
      for k in var[2]:
         print(i, j, k)
```

Such, that it will be something like if the original list had

```
var[0] = "hello", "world"
var[1] = "I", "like"
var[2] = "coding", "Python"
```

then the print will display:

```
loop 1) hello, I, coding, python, 
loop 2) hello, like, coding, python,
loop 3) world, I, coding, python
loop 4) world, like, coding, python
```

Problem is, This is easy to do with static loops, but this whole code depends on what value the user types in. In that case, there will be 4 nested loops.

So what I am thinking, is that possible, with recursion or iter etc?
If yes, Would you please give me the time of your day to explain how? With a sample code?
Thank You ...

Comment: Why are you taking both values from `var[2]` at the same time? Shouldn't the output be `hello, I, coding; hello, I, python; hello, like, coding; hello, like, python; world, I, coding; etc.`?

Comment: Yes exactly like what you said Sir. I may have overlooked some aspects. My actual moto is to write a bruteforce application, where I had in mind that both the values from var[0] and var[1] would stay the same, and the var[3] will loop, so I didn't write that separately. So yes I exactly want what you said. So How can I do it? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your needs correctly, you can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools%20product#itertools.product) to generate the combinations of variables from each list, using a variable to control the number of elements of `var` that are used. For example:

```
import itertools

var = [["hello", "world"],
       ["I", "like"],
       ["coding", "Python"]
       ]
        
for fields in 2, 3:
    print(f"fields = {fields}\n")
    for values in itertools.product(*var[:fields]):
        print(values)
    print()
```

Output:

```
fields = 2

('hello', 'I')
('hello', 'like')
('world', 'I')
('world', 'like')

fields = 3

('hello', 'I', 'coding')
('hello', 'I', 'Python')
('hello', 'like', 'coding')
('hello', 'like', 'Python')
('world', 'I', 'coding')
('world', 'I', 'Python')
('world', 'like', 'coding')
('world', 'like', 'Python')
```

Alternatively you can use recursion, building a list of values for each call to the function which operates on them:

```
def doit(values):
    print(values)
    
def loop(fields, args, values=[]):
    if fields == 0:
        doit(values)
    else:
        for v in args[0]:
            loop(fields-1, args[1:], values + [v])
            
var = [["hello", "world"],
       ["I", "like"],
       ["coding", "Python"]
       ]

loop(2, var)
loop(3, var)
```

Output:

```
['hello', 'I']
['hello', 'like']
['world', 'I']
['world', 'like']

['hello', 'I', 'coding']
['hello', 'I', 'Python']
['hello', 'like', 'coding']
['hello', 'like', 'Python']
['world', 'I', 'coding']
['world', 'I', 'Python']
['world', 'like', 'coding']
['world', 'like', 'Python']
```

Comment: I didn't understand. Why you are writing 2 and 3 statically? And also I am not familiar with iter tools. Would you please explain? Thanks

Comment: The 2 and 3 are *just* to demonstrate the code; the `fields` value would be your user types in. The link to the manual in the answer should give you all the explanation you need, otherwise just search for itertools.product on stackoverflow and you will find lots more examples.

Comment: Thanks. I will try and let you know. But I also heard that recursion is also a way, and I have been trying whole night and can't do it. So if you can help me with that aspect of solving, I can then sleep with 2 solutions in my head :)
 Thanks

Comment: @C0DEV3IL I've added a recursive solution to the answer